# Take every second element of the array in Q#

Tags: programming, q#

Very quick question, I am trying to implement SAT solving in Q# using Grover's Algorithm. I want to take every second element from an array starting at the second element, represented with a range element : `1..2..Length(array)`. I am not very experienced and I am trying to find a nice and clean way to do so, without too much unnecessary for loop. Could someone help ?

Comment: For people looking to for a specific function to do the trick : the [`RangeAsIntArray`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.convert.rangeasintarray) from the Microsoft.Quantum.Convert library will do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array with every second element starting from the second one using the expression `array[1..2...]`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you input the range type directly and the array methods implicitly convert from the range element to an int array ?

Comment: Yes; from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/language/expressions/itemaccessexpressions#array-item-access-and-array-slicing: "If the expression inside the brackets is fo type Range then the new expression will contain an array of all items indexed by the specified Range."